# Matching Code in SQL Server without using Cursor

Tags: sql-server, matching

I have a project where I store Stickers that a user has, and I want to match the user to other users that they can trade with.

The tables I have are:

```
User
-------------- 
UserId


Sticker
-------------
Id


UserStickers
-------------
UserId
StickerId
Count
```

Example Data:

```
User
-------------
'FFE16530-E42B-48F5-9CE2-A4D58E94C1D1'
'F4EF0B59-81AB-41BF-8FB8-BE4E138D294B'
'F1A2F44A-EFD3-4AA9-8210-D4977C68E4A5'
'148CFBB4-94D5-4F85-A2BF-A155EC60DF18'

Sticker
-------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

UserStickers
-------------
'FFE16530-E42B-48F5-9CE2-A4D58E94C1D1', 1, 2
'FFE16530-E42B-48F5-9CE2-A4D58E94C1D1', 2, 1
'FFE16530-E42B-48F5-9CE2-A4D58E94C1D1', 3, 3
'F4EF0B59-81AB-41BF-8FB8-BE4E138D294B', 1, 3
'F4EF0B59-81AB-41BF-8FB8-BE4E138D294B', 2, 1
'F4EF0B59-81AB-41BF-8FB8-BE4E138D294B', 4, 3
'F4EF0B59-81AB-41BF-8FB8-BE4E138D294B', 5, 2
'F4EF0B59-81AB-41BF-8FB8-BE4E138D294B', 6, 1
'F1A2F44A-EFD3-4AA9-8210-D4977C68E4A5', 1, 2
'F1A2F44A-EFD3-4AA9-8210-D4977C68E4A5', 4, 3
'F1A2F44A-EFD3-4AA9-8210-D4977C68E4A5', 8, 2
'F1A2F44A-EFD3-4AA9-8210-D4977C68E4A5', 10, 3
'148CFBB4-94D5-4F85-A2BF-A155EC60DF18', 1, 1
'148CFBB4-94D5-4F85-A2BF-A155EC60DF18', 4, 5
'148CFBB4-94D5-4F85-A2BF-A155EC60DF18', 7, 2
'148CFBB4-94D5-4F85-A2BF-A155EC60DF18', 8, 2
'148CFBB4-94D5-4F85-A2BF-A155EC60DF18', 9, 2
'148CFBB4-94D5-4F85-A2BF-A155EC60DF18', 10, 2
```

I would like to find the best matches for a given user. IE, what other users have stickers they don't. But I also need to know what stickers the original user can give to the other users.

I created a Function `StickerNeeds`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION StickerNeeds ( @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER )
RETURNS @StickerNeeds TABLE
   (
    StickerId     INT
   )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SearchUsersStickers TABLE
    (
        StickerId int
    );

    INSERT INTO @SearchUsersStickers
    SELECT StickerId 
    FROM UserStickers
    WHERE UserId = @UserId;

    INSERT @StickerNeeds
        SELECT
            S.Id
        FROM
            Stickers S
        LEFT JOIN
            @SearchUsersStickers SUS
        ON
            S.Id = SUS.StickerId
        WHERE
            SUS.StickerId IS NULL       
    RETURN
END
```

I am now trying to write my matching code, and I can get a good top twenty users to give stickers to the original user. However calculating a count of what stickers they need in return is proving difficult without a cursor, which runs slowly.

Here is what I currently have, however my final statement to generate the stickers to give back returns nothing.

```
DECLARE @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'FFE16530-E42B-48F5-9CE2-A4D58E94C1D1'

DECLARE @UserMatches TABLE
(
 UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
 StickerTake int,
 StickerGive int
);

INSERT INTO @UserMatches
SELECT TOP 20
    UserId,
    Count(*),
    NULL
FROM
    UserStickers US
INNER JOIN
    StickerNeeds(@UserId) SUN
ON
    US.StickerId = SUN.StickerId
WHERE
    US.[Count] > 1
GROUP BY
    UserId
ORDER BY
    Count(*) DESC

-- Find Stickers to Give AND UPDATE @UserMatches
SELECT
    UM.UserId,
    COUNT(*) As StickerCount
FROM
    (SELECT
            US.StickerId AS StickerId
        FROM
            dbo.UserStickers US
        WHERE
            US.UserId = @UserId
            AND US.[Count] > 1
        ) STG -- StickerToGive
LEFT JOIN
    UserStickers US
ON
    US.StickerId = STG.StickerId
LEFT JOIN
    @UserMatches UM
ON
    US.UserId = UM.UserId
WHERE
    US.StickerId IS NULL
GROUP BY
    UM.UserId


SELECT * FROM @UserMatches
```

Ideally @UserMatches would contain the User Matched, the count of sticker the origin user can take and the count of stickers the origin user can give. I can't calculate give without using a cursor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Chris-MayhemSoftware, what would you like me to expand upon?

Comment: Mind adding some test(dummy) data to your question?

Comment: This is much better after your edit. The original post was not framed as a question.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, no problem

Comment: @Chris-MayhemSoftware, sorry, desperation and staring at this problem for too long!

Comment: No problem.  I know what it what its like :)  I was thinking you might be able to do all this in a query rather than using a function.

Comment: The function is just to be used in the Query at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain properly I guess I was thinking you might be able to get all the info via a single query rather than writing any t-sql.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested so might need some tweaking.  But I think it can all be returned in a single query with multiple subqueries.

```
select top 20 UserId, 
  (select count(*) from UserStickers u3 where u3.UserId = u1.UserId and u3.count > 1 and u3.StickerId not in (select StickerId from UserStickers u4 where u4.UserId = <origin_User> and u4.count > 1) ) as CountOriginCanTake, 
  (select count(*) from UserStickers u5 where u5.UserId = <origin_User> and u5.count > 1 and u5.StickerId not in (select StickerId from UserStickers u6 where u6.UserId = u1.UserId and u6.count > 1 ) ) as CountOriginCanGive
from UserStickers u1
where u1.StickerId not in (select StickerId from UserStickers u2 where u2.UserId = <origin_User> and u2.count > 1)
and u1.count > 1
group by UserId
order by 2 desc
```

Just paste the origin User id in place of origin_User

Comment: I'm getting an error:
The multi-part identifier "u2.userId" could not be bound.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo - u2.UserId should have been u4.UserId. Also I think you'll need "count > 1" in a few places.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok Awesome, this runs now, but after a while returns this error. I assume it's because the UserId is a GUID? Error:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '003082F0-35B8-434B-9BBE-AF0388205DE9' to data type int.

Comment: Mmm that is weird.  I found another typo in there which I just corrected.  Give it another try to see if that helps.

Comment: Just finished and it worked great, however took 21 mins. With a cursor I got it to 1 min. I know we can add indexes and add more power to the server, but as a base is there anyway to make this faster?

Comment: How many rows in each table are you talking? You could look at creating an indexed view (sqlserver's equivalent of a materialized view) and querying that instead.  But seriously creating indexes  is the first thing I'd work on - this will make a massive difference to performance. Once you've created indexes ensure your index stats are regularly optimised. Another thing to note is that guid's are not great for performance. It might be worth creating a integer candidate key to use as your clustered index on the user table, you could still have guid as your primary key.

Comment: We have test data in at the moment. 680 stickers, 1,000 users, and around 400,000 entries in UserStickers. We definitely will be adding indexes and have already discussed using an integer candidate key, so I think we definitely have to do this. Was just wondering the best query to increase performance even more.

Comment: Best to tune indexes as part of assessing the best approach to ensure you are comparing apples with apples.  A query with effective indexes may end up being much more efficient than a cursor - however without effective indexes and stats the query might be much slower.  This will help http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/

Comment: Cheers, we'll create a few versions, add indexes, run tests and work out what best to do. I'll give you the accept for a working query and all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're requirements are quite tough, my query matches users who can give stickers to those who need stickers. It prioritises matches with the user who can give the most stickers to a receiver.

```
;WITH UserNeeds
AS
(
    SELECT UserId, StickerId
    FROM User U
    CROSS APPLY Sticker S
    EXCEPT
    SELECT UserId, StickerId
    FROM UserStickers
),
UserGives
As
(
    SELECT UserId, StickerId, Num - 1 As Num
    FROM UserStickers
    WHERE Num > 1
),
PossibleMatches
As
(
    SELECT UG.UserId GivingUser, UG.StickerId, UN.UserId ReceivingUser, UG.Num
    From UserNeeds UN
    INNER JOIN UserGives UG
        ON UN.StickerId = UG.StickerId
),
BestMatches
As
(
    SELECT GivingUser, ReceivingUser, Count(*) as Matches, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GivingUser ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS RN
    FROM PossibleMatches
    GROUP BY GivingUser, ReceivingUser
)
SELECT PM.*
FROM PossibleMatches PM
INNER JOIN BestMatches BM
    ON PM.GivingUSer = BM.GivingUser AND PM.ReceivingUser = BM.ReceivingUser
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY PM.GivingUser, PM.ReceivingUser
```

Comment: On the first line I'm getting the error: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 I have updated the query, please try again.

Comment: In the actual database we have a lot of data. With my cursor I got results in about 1 min. However with your query it got to 12 mins before I ended the execution. If it helps, returning just a top 20 is all that is needed.